# unfortunately package installer has stopped android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to create a live wallpaper in android. My app works fine on emulator but on my phone, I am not able to install it.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:name="GIFWallpaperService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="Wallpaper Example "
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" >
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" >
        </meta-data>
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

wallpaper.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wallpaper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="GIF Wallpaper"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:thumbnail="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
</wallpaper>
```

Whenever I try to run my code on emulator everything works fine but when I copy 
"app-debug" to my phone and try to install it does not work.
After installation is complete I get two options :

1. Open the app.
2. Done.

If I click Done nothing happens and afterwards if I click my installed app icon it says `app is not installed`.

If I click open at the end of installation it says `unfortunately package installer has stopped android`

Comment: I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314266/android-permission-denial-starting-intent-for-wallpaper-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here : 
[Android Permission Denial starting Intent for Wallpaper Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314266/android-permission-denial-starting-intent-for-wallpaper-settings)

I had `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"` at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Debuggable is set to false right? Does not that mean that you can not debug with it? Try removing 'android:debuggable="false",'and see if it works.

Comment: Same as before. Not Working.

Comment: Why not try swtiching up the intents.